# access layer weights through metric

Tags: keras, metrics

I am trying to monitor the number of negative weights in the diagonal of a certain layer during training. The custom metric I wrote does not work however:

```
def less_zero(_,__):
    off=K.tf.count_nonzero(tf.less(model.get_weights()[0].diagonal(), 0))
    return off
```

When I check the weights after training I always get negative ones, which do not show up in the training progress window

Answer (score 0):

At the end I did not bother accessing the weights through the metric and used a LambdaCallback with model.get_weights() instead, which printed the number of negative weights I wanted to monitor.